# Any Ubuntu 16.04 LTS compatible Bluetooth keyboard mouse combos?

Tags: wireless-keyboards

Getting new Aleutia R50 computer with Ubuntu 16.04 on it...will be new to Linux. Has Bluetooth 4.2 on it. Tried looking in stores and online for a Bluetooth compatible keyboard mouse combo that will work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Any brands or brand links would be awesome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Where does it say shopping recommendations are off topic?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have yet to find a Bluetooth mouse or keyboard that doesn't work in Linux. And that's saying something - I've used many Bluetooth input devices let the years. So you can rest pretty well assured that any one you choose, even if not marketed as Linux-compatible, will be.